# Single Sign On on Google Apps

Tags: single-sign-on, google-apps, mcc

Can I from my website, once a user is authenticated, let him login into GMail, Google+, Youtube or other Google service skipping the login screen? Does Google's SSO work this way?

If this is possible, can this be done with my login and do the SSO on behalf of their account? Maybe through some authorization token they give me, instead of their passwords. I read about this about using the Google MCC for that.

Is all this possible?

Answer (score 0):

IF

the user is a Google Apps user

AND

you provide a SAML IDP

AND

the Google Apps domain is configured to use you IDP

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation